# htaccess Subdomain don't work with mod_rewrite enable

Tags: .htaccess

I already searched for many tutorials and nothing worked to me.
I want create virtual subdomains with htacces but when I enable mod_rewrite my software disable the original urls. For example:

```
mod_rewrite disabled:
http://domain.com/listings.php?category=35

mod_rewrite enabled:
http://domain.com/35-finance/listings.html
```

When enabled I can't acces http://domain.com/listings.php?category=35...

In my htacces, if mod_rewrite disabled, this works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-_]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) listings.php?category=%2 [NC,QSA]
```

But if enabled, it don't work, it don't understand the 'category' parameter.

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/%1/listings.html [L]
```

I'm **redirected** to the correct page, but I want to keep the subdomain in the browser bar...

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/listings.html [L]
```

It results in internal server error.

I really tried many things before in this week, but nothing works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-_]+).domain.com [NC]
>
> RewriteRule (.*) listings.php?category=%2 [NC,QSA]
>
> But if enabled, it don't work, it don't understand the 'category' parameter.

The `%2` means to match the second pattern in the `RewriteCond`s. In this cae, the second pattern is the `([a-z0-9-_]+)` part.

> In my htacces, if mod_rewrite disabled, this works:

If mod_rewrite is truly disabled, then those rules aren't being used.

> RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/%1/listings.html [L]
>
> I'm redirected to the correct page, but I want to keep the subdomain in the browser bar...

If you supply a domain in the RewriteRule, you will **always** be redirected, you need to supply a path only (like `/%1/listings.html`). If the domains are all part of the same VirtualHost, this should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have not explained properly. mod_rewrite is not disabled... the search engine friendly option from the software  is disabled :). But I got tired of trying by htaccess, as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got solve the problem using this php code: (www.gitme.net/php/ >> Gitme url2subdomain  )

```
<?php

// code by büyücü.   www.gitme.net/php/

$full_url = sprintf($HTTP_HOST);
$subdomain = "";

for($i = 0;$i<=strlen($full_url);$i++)
{

  $dummy = substr($full_url,$i,1);

  if($dummy == ".")
  {
   break;
  }

  $subdomain = $subdomain.$dummy;

}

//



if ($subdomain <> "www")
{

  switch($subdomain)
  {
   case "gazeteler":
     $real_url = "http://www.gitme.net/gazeteler.htm";
     break;
   case "guzel-sozler":
     $real_url = "http://www.gitme.net/guzel-sozler.php";
     break;
    case "burclar":
     $real_url = "http://www.gitme.net/burclar.html";
     break;
      default : $real_url="http://www.gitme.net/";

  }

 include "$real_url";
 exit;
}


?>
```